# How to properly read fixed-width format files

Tags: r, fixed-width, read.fwf

Relatively new to R and R Studio and I'm trying to reformat a text file to run some analysis on the data within it. I'm currently trying to use read.fwf to tidy the data but seem to be doing something wrong, resulting in various errors. I've attempted to resolve these problems by referring to sources/guides but am still pretty stuck. Any suggestions? (code, examples of the information in the text file, and the desired format are below).

**Current Code:**

```
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
read.fwf("AK_JAN_2017_TMAS_", widths =c(1,2,6,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,4,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3), header = false, sep = "", row.names = c("Record Type", "FIPS", "Station ID", "Direction of Travel code", "Lane of Travel", "Year of Data", "Month of Data", "Day of Data", "Hour of Data", "Vehicle Class", "Open", "Total Weight of Vehicle", "Number of Axles", "A-axle Weight", "A-B Axle Spacing", "B-axle Weight", "B-C Axle Spacing", "C-axle Weight", "C-D Axle Spacing", "D-axle Spacing", "D-E Axle Spacing", "E-axle Weight", "E-F Axle Spacing", "F-axle Weight", "F-G Axle Spacing", "G-axle Weight", "G-H Axle Spacing", "H-axle Weight", "H-I Axle Spacing", "I-axle Weight", "I-J Axle Spacing", "J-axle Weight", "J-K Axle Spacing", "K-axle Weight", "K-L Axle Spacing", "L-axle Weight", "L-M Axle Spacing", "M-axle Weight"), col.names = NULL, n = -1, buffersize = 2000, fileencoding = "" )
```

**Sample of the text file:**

> W02000103311701021610061031206057054056013054096054015053015038
>   W02000103311701021606055024403039038084005121
>   W02000103311701021609067028505040038054013065104062012064
>   W02000103311701021705073004302024043019
>   W02000103311701021710066045606055070075015088094085018086018067
>   W02000103311701021710080044706052069075015087096083018085018065
>   W02000103311701021805076007402034056040
>   W02000103311701021805076004802025043023
>   W02000103311701021905077002402010051014
>   W02000103311701021905072004702026042021
>   W02000103311701021906044020303068053067015068
>   W02000103311701022006066014803057045049014042
>   W02000103311701022006053012903058041038014033
>   W02000103311701022005060003702020043017
>   W02000103311701022006063009503046047023014026
>   W02000103311701022105072006602036060030
>   W02000103311701022206068017703045050059015073
>   W02000103311701022305065006902033037036
>   W02000103311701030005066008802032038056
>   W02000103311701030305066008202037063045

**Desired format of the data:**

[image]

**Issues:**

```
 library(readr)
 library(tidyr)
 AK_JAN_2017_TMAS_ <- read.table("~/R Studio Sessions/AK_JAN_2017_TMAS_.txt", quote="\"", comment.char="")
   View(AK_JAN_2017_TMAS_)
 left<-c(2,4,10,11,12,14,16,18,20,22,25,29,31,34,37,40,43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70,73,76,79,82,85,88,91,94,97,100,103)
 right<-c(3,9,10,11,13,15,17,19,21,24,28,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105)
 df <- data.frame(matrix(numeric(length(x)*length(left)),ncol=length(left)))
Error in numeric(length(x) * length(left)) : object 'x' not found
 for (i in 1:length(input.set)) {
     stop <- nchar(x[i])
     for (j in 1:length(left)) {
         df[i,j] <- as.numeric(substr(input.set[i], left[j], right[j]))
         if (right[j] ==  stop) break
     }
 }
Error in length(input.set) : object 'input.set' not found
 df <- data.frame(AK_JAN_2017_TMAS_(numeric(length(x)*length(left)),ncol=length(left)))
Error in AK_JAN_2017_TMAS_(numeric(length(x) * length(left)), ncol = length(left)) : 
  could not find function "AK_JAN_2017_TMAS_"
 for (i in 1:length(input.set)) {
     stop <- nchar(x[i])
     for (j in 1:length(left)) {
         df[i,j] <- as.numeric(substr(input.set[i], left[j], right[j]))
         if (right[j] ==  stop) break
     }
 }

 df <- data.frame(matrix(numeric(length(x)*length(left)),ncol=length(left)))
Error in numeric(length(x) * length(left)) : object 'x' not found
 for (i in 1:length('AK_JAN_2017_TMAS_'.set)) {
Error: unexpected symbol in "for (i in 1:length('AK_JAN_2017_TMAS_'.set"
     stop <- nchar(x[i])
Error in nchar(x[i]) : object 'x' not found
     for (j in 1:length(left)) {
         df[i,j] <- as.numeric(substr(input.set[i], left[j], right[j]))
         if (right[j] ==  stop) break
     }
Error in substr(input.set[i], left[j], right[j]) : 
  object 'input.set' not found
 }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"


And a few changes I attempted to make:

     df <- data.frame(matrix(numeric(length(x)*length(left)),ncol=length(left)))
    for (i in 1:length('AK_JAN_2017_TMAS_'.set)) {
        stop <- nchar(x[i])
        for (j in 1:length(left)) {
            df[i,j] <- as.numeric(substr(input.set[i], left[j], right[j]))
            if (right[j] ==  stop) break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example in r](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The link I provided, will tell you how. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit the question accordingly. You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us some efforts. Cheers.

Comment: What error message did you get? Are you sure that you want row.names rather than column names and is `false` defined?

Comment: Do you mean `read_fwf` instead of `read.fwf`? Since you're loading `readr`..

Comment: I've made some changes to the post reflecting (to a degree) the examples you linked.

Answer (score 1):

The varying line lengths are likely to be a problem. You can do this line by line as follows:

Construct two lists that show the value boundaries (we skip the "W"). These will be used to extract the substrings for the variables.

```
left<-c(2,4,10,11,12,14,16,18,20,22,25,29,31,34,37,40,
        43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70,73,76,79,82,85,88,91,94,97,100,103)

right<-c(3,9,10,11,13,15,17,19,21,24,28,30,33,36,39,42,
         45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105)
```

Loop on the input line generating the numbers from the substrings. You only want to process the last possible value for each to prevent `NA`s, so a sentinel variable (`stop`) is created from the number of characters in each data string.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(numeric(length(input.set)*length(left)),ncol=length(left)))
for (i in 1:length(input.set)) {
    stop <- nchar(input.set[i])
    for (j in 1:length(left)) {
        df[i,j] <- as.numeric(substr(input.set[i], left[j], right[j]))
        if (right[j] ==  stop) break
    }
}
```

You can then add names for the columns.

```
nvals <- c("FIPS","StaID","Dir","Lane","Year","Month","Day","Hour","Class",
           "Open", "TotW", "Axles",
           "AW","ASp","BW","BSp","CW","CSp","DW","DSp",
           "EW","ESp","FW","FSp","GW","GSp","HW","HSp",
           "IW","ISp","JW","JSp","KW","KSp","LW","LSp","MW")
names(df) <- nvals
```

Here are a couple of lines from the resulting data frame:

```
  FIPS StaID Dir Lane Year Month Day Hour Class Open TotW Axles AW ASp BW BSp  CW
1    2   103   3    1   17     1   2   16    10   61  312     6 57  54 56  13  54
2    2   103   3    1   17     1   2   16     6   55  244     3 39  38 84   5 121
3    2   103   3    1   17     1   2   16     9   67  285     5 40  38 54  13  65
  CSp DW DSp EW ESp FW FSp GW GSp HW HSp IW ISp JW JSp KW KSp LW LSp MW
1  96 54  15 53  15 38   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0
2   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0
3 104 62  12 64   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0   0  0
```

Comment: This helps so much--Thanks, Edward!

Comment: I am running into a few problems when trying to input the code above--It could be a simple mistake I am making, I am not sure. I have added my issues at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Essentially, I am running into issues of the object 'x' not being defined in length(x) and input.set not being defined either.

Comment: Sorry. I’ve edited it to change `x` to `input.set`; I failed to change all the occurrences. BTW, you can use the `readLines` function to get the file contents, as in `input.set <- readLines(“filename.txt”)`.